# inspecting responsive styles with Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, responsive

I'm building an application and by far the weakest part of my game is Style and Design. But, I'm having one particular problem at the moment. I'm trying to make my dashboard responsive but when I look at the dashboard as an `iphone 6` with my chrome inspector the screen zooms out really far and everything breaks... Here is a screen shot of what I mean.

[image]

See how the content is really far away... I really don't know how to fix this? Any idea what I could be doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try to add this to your HTML's `<head></head>`:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Reference: [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_viewport.asp)